# how can i get whole web page include the fragment web

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

i've tried with with urllib and request library but the data in fragment was not written in .html file. help me please :(

Here with the request

```
url = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxx.co.jp/InService/delivery/#/V=2/partsList/Element.PartsList%3A%3AVj0xfnsicklkIjoiQzEtQlVMTERPWkVSLUxfSVNfQzNfLl9CVUxMRE9aRVItTF8uXzgwXy5fRDg1RVNTLTJfLl9LSSIsIm9wIjpbIkMxLUJVTExET1pFUi1MX0lTX0MzXy5fQlVMTERPWkVSLUxfLl84MF8uX0Q4NUVTUy0yXy5fS0kiLCJJU19QQl8uX0Q4NUVTUy0yXy5fS0ktMDAwMDMiLCJJU19QQl8uX0Q4NUVTUy0yXy5fS0ktMDAwMDNfLl9BMCIsIlBMX0MxLUJVTExET1pFUi1MX0FDXy5fRDg1RVNTLTJfLl9LSS0wMDAwM18uX0EwMDEwMDEwIl0sIm5uIjoyMTQsInRzIjoxNTc5ODM0OTIwMDE5fQ?filterId=Product%3A%3AVj0xfnsicklkIjoiUk9PVCBQUk9EVUNUIiwib3AiOlsiUk9PVCBQUk9EVUNUIiwiQzEtQlVMTERPWkVSLUwiLCJDMl8uX0JVTExET1pFUi1MXy5fODAiLCJDM18uX0JVTExET1pFUi1MXy5fODBfLl9EODVFU1MtMl8uX0tJIl0sIm5uIjo2OTcsInRzIjoxNTc2NTY0MjMwMDg1fQ&bomFilterState=false'

response = requests.get(url)

print(response)
```

here with the urllib

```
url = 'https://xxxxxxx.co.jp/InService/delivery/?view=print#/V=2/partsList/Element.PartsList::Vj0xfnsicklkIjoiQzEtQlVMTERPWkVSLUxfSVNfQzNfLl9CVUxMRE9aRVItTF8uXzgwXy5fRDg1RVNTLTJfLl9LSSIsIm9wIjpbIkMxLUJVTExET1pFUi1MX0lTX0MzXy5fQlVMTERPWkVSLUxfLl84MF8uX0Q4NUVTUy0yXy5fS0kiLCJJU19QQl8uX0Q4NUVTUy0yXy5fS0ktMDAwMDMiLCJJU19QQl8uX0Q4NUVTUy0yXy5fS0ktMDAwMDNfLl9BMCIsIlBMX0MxLUJVTExET1pFUi1MX0FDXy5fRDg1RVNTLTJfLl9LSS0wMDAwM18uX0EwMDEwMDIwIl0sIm5uIjoyMjUsInRzIjoxNTgwMDk1MDYzNjIyfQ?filterId=Product::Vj0xfnsicklkIjoiUk9PVCBQUk9EVUNUIiwib3AiOlsiUk9PVCBQUk9EVUNUIiwiQzEtQlVMTERPWkVSLUwiLCJDMl8uX0JVTExET1pFUi1MXy5fODAiLCJDM18uX0JVTExET1pFUi1MXy5fODBfLl9EODVFU1MtMl8uX0tJIl0sIm5uIjo2OTcsInRzIjoxNTc2NTY0MjMwMDg1fQ&bomFilterState=false'

request = urllib.request.Request(url)
string = '%s:%s' % ('xx','xx')

base64string = base64.standard_b64encode(string.encode('utf-8'))

request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string.decode('utf-8'))
u = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
webContent = u.read()
```

[here is home of the web page (url:https://xxxxxx.co.jp/InService/delivery/#/V=2/home)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCaXH.png)

[and here is the page that i want to get the data (url: https://xxxxxxx.co.jp/InService/delivery/?view=print#/V=2/partsList/Element.PartsList::Vj0xfnsicklkIjoiQzE...)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sc1n9.png)

so every i request the web page like in the 2 picture, the html content is must be the html in picture 1 because in picture 2 is the fragment

Comment: It isn’t clear what exactly you’re asking. There are plenty of resources available on web scraping, have you done any research?

Comment: sorry if isnt clear hehe, i was edited my question with the picture

Answer (score 1):

If all you would like is the html of the webpage, just use requests as you have in the first example, except instead of print(response) use print(response.content).

To save it into a file use:

```
import requests
url = 'https://xxxxxxx.co.jp/InService/delivery/?view=print#/V=2/partsList/Element.PartsList::Vj0xfnsicklkIjoiQzEtQlVMTERPWkVSLUxfSVNfQzNfLl9CVUxMRE9aRVItTF8uXzgwXy5fRDg1RVNTLTJfLl9LSSIsIm9wIjpbIkMxLUJVTExET1pFUi1MX0lTX0MzXy5fQlVMTERPWkVSLUxfLl84MF8uX0Q4NUVTUy0yXy5fS0kiLCJJU19QQl8uX0Q4NUVTUy0yXy5fS0ktMDAwMDMiLCJJU19QQl8uX0Q4NUVTUy0yXy5fS0ktMDAwMDNfLl9BMCIsIlBMX0MxLUJVTExET1pFUi1MX0FDXy5fRDg1RVNTLTJfLl9LSS0wMDAwM18uX0EwMDEwMDIwIl0sIm5uIjoyMjUsInRzIjoxNTgwMDk1MDYzNjIyfQ?filterId=Product::Vj0xfnsicklkIjoiUk9PVCBQUk9EVUNUIiwib3AiOlsiUk9PVCBQUk9EVUNUIiwiQzEtQlVMTERPWkVSLUwiLCJDMl8uX0JVTExET1pFUi1MXy5fODAiLCJDM18uX0JVTExET1pFUi1MXy5fODBfLl9EODVFU1MtMl8uX0tJIl0sIm5uIjo2OTcsInRzIjoxNTc2NTY0MjMwMDg1fQ&bomFilterState=false'
with open("output.html", 'w+') as f:
    response = requests.get(url)
    f.write(response.content)
```

If you need a certain part of the webpage, use BeautifulSoup.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://xxxxxxx.co.jp/InService/delivery/?view=print#/V=2/partsList/Element.PartsList::Vj0xfnsicklkIjoiQzEtQlVMTERPWkVSLUxfSVNfQzNfLl9CVUxMRE9aRVItTF8uXzgwXy5fRDg1RVNTLTJfLl9LSSIsIm9wIjpbIkMxLUJVTExET1pFUi1MX0lTX0MzXy5fQlVMTERPWkVSLUxfLl84MF8uX0Q4NUVTUy0yXy5fS0kiLCJJU19QQl8uX0Q4NUVTUy0yXy5fS0ktMDAwMDMiLCJJU19QQl8uX0Q4NUVTUy0yXy5fS0ktMDAwMDNfLl9BMCIsIlBMX0MxLUJVTExET1pFUi1MX0FDXy5fRDg1RVNTLTJfLl9LSS0wMDAwM18uX0EwMDEwMDIwIl0sIm5uIjoyMjUsInRzIjoxNTgwMDk1MDYzNjIyfQ?filterId=Product::Vj0xfnsicklkIjoiUk9PVCBQUk9EVUNUIiwib3AiOlsiUk9PVCBQUk9EVUNUIiwiQzEtQlVMTERPWkVSLUwiLCJDMl8uX0JVTExET1pFUi1MXy5fODAiLCJDM18uX0JVTExET1pFUi1MXy5fODBfLl9EODVFU1MtMl8uX0tJIl0sIm5uIjo2OTcsInRzIjoxNTc2NTY0MjMwMDg1fQ&bomFilterState=false'
response = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)
```

use inspect element and find the Tag of the table that you want in the second image, eg. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybjmx.jpg.

then use:

```
found = response.find('div', attrs={"class":"x-carousel__body no-scroll"}).find_all('ul')
```

For the ebay example I linked above.

This should return that table which you can then do whatever you like with.

Comment: i've tried that too and its seems like not get the data in fragment :(

Comment: could you explain what you mean by "data in fragment"

Comment: maybe you can see the edited question that i asked, ty

Comment: Ok i have improved the answer. As i didnt have access to your specific example, i used ebay instead but should be the same process. Just replace the class and div tags with your own examples.